# Challenges and Considerations in Unfunded Remote Research for Researchers from Restricted Countries

Tags: research-process, funding, academic-life, international-students, remote-work

I am interested in understanding the nuances and core objectives of pursuing remote research studies, particularly in scenarios where funding is not available and the researcher's nationality (e.g., Iranian) poses additional challenges.

What are the main goals or benefits for an individual engaging in unfunded remote research, especially when facing restrictions due to their nationality?

I am eager to hear from individuals who have navigated similar challenges or have insights into how researchers can maximize their learning and contribution under such circumstances.

Comment: Afaik a lot of similar blocks are topic-related. Probably you can expect more problems in a nuclear chemistry topic as in population genetics. Another option if the project runs in the name of a neutral country, like Saudi Arabia.